# Sqlmap executed query always return 4 lines of incomplete result

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I have a table which stored UID for users and I'm doing security check for my sqlserver 2008R2, currently I've successfully connected to my linked server using sqlmap and I tried to execute query injecting as below

```
select UID from XXXX where NickName = 'XXX'
```

and it returned

```
[*] A
[*] 1
[*]
[*]
```

No matter what queries I've executed, it always returned 4 lines of incomplete results. I'm wondering why it causing this problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad to have you here. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking. I don't know what's in your database or why it would be unexpected that you get 4 rows of result from your query. Perhaps there are simply 4 rows that match the query condition on `NickName`? I must be missing something.

Comment: Hi, the database contained large data of nicknames, the expected result of this query should only have 1 result instead of giving 4 incomplete results. Thanks for answering

Comment: The sqlmap command was ```sqlmap.py --dbms=mssql -u --data "" -p "" --random-agent --keep-alive --encoding=BIG5 --sql-shell```